# what is the explanation of the conditions of interference?

Tags: interference

I know the conditions of interference.but I want to know the explanation of the conditions.like we know for interference,the sources should be coherent.but why? I want to know those explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Coherence of sources imply that the phase difference of the light beams at a particular point on the screen does not change with time. If the phase difference changes with time than the bright part will no longer remain bright and so for the dark part. Hence you would have no interference pattern.

Comment: in fact I used that as an example.I want to know the other explanations of the other conditions